# Recursive SQL query between two tables in JPA

Tags: java, sql, database, spring-boot, jpa

We are having two tables PROPOSAL and SUB_PROMOTION linked using SUB_PROMOTION_ID column.

Columns of table:

```
SUB_PROMOTION : SUB_PROMOTION_ID & PARENT_SUB_PROMOTION_ID

PROPOSAL : PROPOSAL_ID & SUB_PROMOTION_ID
```

We are checking if a particular SUB_PROMOTION_ID from the SUB_PROMOTION table is having a PROPOSAL and if it is not existing we are checking for the PARENT_SUB_PROMOTION_ID from the SUB_PROMOTION table itself. The algorithm goes like:

```
solve(id):
    if (PROPOSAL.SUB_PROMOTION_ID = id exists): return id
        
    parent_id = select SUB_PROMOTION.PARENT_SUB_PROMOTION_ID where SUB_PROMOTION.SUB_PROMOTION_ID = id

    if (parent_id == null): return id
        
    solve(parent_id) 

solve(sub_promotion_id)
```

We need a single SQL query which checks this recursively.

Comment: I didn't check in a while but the last time I did JPA (or more specifically JPQL) wouldn't support recursive queries. You'd need to use plain SQL here.

Comment: Can you help in writing the plain SQL that is required?

Comment: Have a look at the common table expressions, e.g. [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) and try it with your database.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server (Microsoft JDBC Driver)

Comment: JPQL doesn't support recursive queries, you can use a native query instead: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/